# Formula.recalculateFormulas() returning System.HandledException: Script-thrown exception(System Code) When State and Country populated on Lead

Tags: apex, country-and-state, system

LeadTrigger BeforeInsert has some logic that relies on the formula fields on Lead in the logic and using the Formula.recalculateFormulas() to get valid values in these fields.

This logic was working fine until we enabled the State and Country/Territory Picklists in our Org. happening intermittently and only when State and Country values are populated on the record.

Replacing the Formula.recalculateFormulas() with some custom logic to calculate the formula field value within the Apex Class resolved the issue but keen to understand why the Formula.recalculateFormulas() throwing the exception as the above is only a temporary fix and would be difficult to keep mimicking formula field calculations in Apex instead of using the system method.

[image: Code Snapshot:]

Checklist:

State and country values defined in the picklist.

Dependency is defined correctly.

Comment: About the only thing I can think of is that you may have a formula that references the state/county/territory picklists but your object instance doesn't have that data populated, so the call to `recalculateFormulas()` is attempting to query for the record (but it doesn't have an Id yet, owing to this code being in a before insert trigger). No idea if that's actually the case, but it could be something to look into.